# Removing Alpha Channel from Bitmap (RGBA to RGB)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

i was wondering if someone has a code to do this or point me in the right direction, i tried elemenating the 4th byte in each 4 bytes of a pixel, but it never worked. i opened the 32bit image in hex editor, it was kinda all the same sequence of bytes. resolution is 66x66 dots per inch

thanks

Comment: By "removing alpha channel", do you mean setting all alpha values to fully opaque?

Comment: no, removing them totally, so the file is RGB insted of RGBA (24 bpp)

Comment: In that case, you probably need to look at the file header - update that so it indicates that there is no alpha channel, as well as stripping out the alpha bytes. Details depend on the specific file format. Also, some file formats use red-green-blue-padding, padding 24 bit colour to 32-bits-per-pixel because 32-bit aligned data is usually more efficient to work with (though in principle the padding could be added as the file is loaded, of course), so dropping the alpha channel may simply mean changing the header so the alpha is ignored.

Comment: IOW, more details are needed to answer - what file format and perhaps what library?

Comment: @Steve314: i did all that, and viewed in a hex editor, still, when i try to view the original image in the same hex editor it shows 3 bytes repeated over and over again, eventho its a screen shot, also im using XGetImage on linux then converted to Bitmap manually

Comment: "Bitmap" is not a specific file format. Do you mean Microsoft BMP?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "convert" program can do this. It is part of the ImageMagick package.